# Displaying row data from Angular Material Table into another component

Tags: angular, datatable, angular-material, angular-components

I have two components. The first component contains Angular Material Table while the second one going to display the details of the row clicked in table.

The first component:

```
    const ELEMENT_DATA: GoodsList[] = [
    {initial: 'J', eta: '20-01-2020', src: 'IN'},
    {initial: 'N', eta: '20-01-2020', src: 'ON''}
]
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="ordered">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Initial </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.initial}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="eta">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ETA </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.eta}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="srt">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> SRC </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.src}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="getRecord(row)"></tr>
</table>
```

Now the function getRecord() is working as intended.

```
    getRecord(row: GoodsList){
    console.log(row);
    }
```

The data is captured inside row variable but now how can I pass it into another component based on what I clicked?

Comment: Does your "other component" is a child ? a parent ? Or maybe you have a `<router-outlet>` ?

Comment: @Emilien both of the components are on the same level, so it's not parent-child relation

Comment: Maybe you can store your `row` into a service with a Subject. After that, you inject this service in both component.

Comment: @Emilien can you elaborate with example? Subject is still new for me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of using  a service (The example is about users managment) :

- In your UserService, declare a property user with type Subject.

```js
user: Subject<User> = new Subject();
```

- Expose it to outside as observable:

```js
user$: Observable<User>
...
this.user$ = this.user.asObservable();
```

- Login function will update the private user Subject.

```js
login(userName: string, password: string) {
  //...
  this.user.next(new User("First name", "Last name"));
}
```

- In your UserComponent, subscribe to UserServive's user$ observable to update view.

```js
this.userService.user$.subscribe((userData) => {this.user = userData;});
```

- In your view, simply use string interpolation:

```html
{{user?.firstName}} {{user?.lastName}}
```

Here is the working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/qUR0spZL9hgZkBe8PHw4?p=preview